# Firebase functions vs Multiple requests

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm beginner using firebase and I have a doubt about duplicate data instead use key reference. Let's suppose that I have a list of user comments for a video. Each comment has a user name and avatar. Assuming that the user can change the name and avatar. What is the better options:

1. Keep just the userId in each comment and make more request to get user profile data or
2. Copy the user profile and each comment and use a firebase functions to update the profile data when user change his name or avatar.

Some points to considering:

**OPTION 1**

**Pros**

- Use less storage

**Cons**

- If we have a lot of users using the application, we will have a lot of extra request for get the name and avatar

**OPTION 2**

**Pros**

- Spend more We will execute in backend using firebase functions just when a user change the avatar or name

**Const**

- Use more storage

Example:

```
// OPTION 1
{
  user: {
    user1: {
      name: 'Name 1',
      avatar: 'Avatar 1',
    }
  },
  comments: {
    comment1: {
      text: 'comment',
      user: 'user1'
    }
  }
}

// OPTION 2
{
  user: {
    user1: {
      name: 'Name 1',
      avatar: 'Avatar 1',
    }
  },
  comments: {
    comment1: {
      text: 'comment',
      user: {
        id: 'user1',
        name: 'Name 1',
        avatar: 'Avatar 1',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to achieve, but in general I would recommend you to go with `option 2`.

In Firebase or generally in NoSQL Databases mirroring data is a very good approach. Especially if you want to build an application with high performance. Just don't forget to update your data in each node, whenever it changes.

But one thing you have to be aware is that nesting too deep can also be bad. That's why I think it really depends on the case if it makes sence or not.